# IllegalArgumentException return the value given in object decleration

Tags: java

the bellow code is part of a program that is suppose to throw an IllegalArgumentException if the given value is out of range. But instead, if the given numbers in setTime() is out of range, it would return the corresponding value when the object was created in the main method instead of the desired error message! what is the reason

here is the code:

```
public class MyTime {

    private int hour = 0;
    private int minute = 0;
    private int second = 0;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
// when the value is out of range in setTime(), the value given bellow in t1 is returned
        MyTime t1 = new MyTime (10,10,10);
        t1.setTime(26, 23, 14);
        System.out.println("toString(): " + t1);   
    }

    public MyTime (int hour, int minute, int second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public void setTime (int hour, int minute, int second) {
        try {
            if (hour > 0 && hour < 23 ) {
                this.hour = hour;
            }

            if (minute > 0 && minute < 59 ) {
                this.minute = minute;
            }

            if (second > 0 && second < 59 ) {
                this.second = second;
            }            

        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not do anything if the values are out of range.  It must throw the exception but you just ignore the values if they are invalid.

Comment: Is the code magically supposed to know that it has to throw a particular exception if it fails any `if` condition?

Comment: so were am I suppose to add the exception error!

Comment: You can throw exception like this.
if (hour > 0 && hour < 23 ) {
 this.hour = hour;
}else{
 throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it should ***throw*** the exception. So you shouldn't ***catch*** it inside the method. Remove the ***try{...}catch{..}*** around the ***if*** 's

```
public void setTime (int hour, int minute, int second) {

    if (hour > 0 && hour < 23 ) {
        this.hour = hour;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (minute > 0 && minute < 59 ) {
        this.minute = minute;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (second > 0 && second < 59 ) {
        this.second = second;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw the exception.

```
public void setTime (int hour, int minute, int second) {
    try {
        if (hour > 0 && hour < 23 ) {
            this.hour = hour;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Hour Value");
        }

        if (minute > 0 && minute < 59 ) {
            this.minute = minute;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Minutes Value");
        }

        if (second > 0 && second < 59 ) {
            this.second = second;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Seconds Value");
        }            

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I thought you just add one exception error for the whole method

Comment: @zamzam: only one exception for whole method is enough ; but you need to throw the error in order to execute/catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your code handle outside range values

eg:

```
if (hour > 0 && hour < 23 )
    this.hour = hour;
else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```